# Sum product formula does not work for whole data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been using Sum product formula to count the number of dates between 2 given dates but when i want to count the whole data ignoring the last match from formula then it give 0 answer whereas it should give the answer for whole data any help will be appreciated.

I have attached a sheet link below for better understanding.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B>=E1),--(B2:B<=F1),--(A2:A=E2))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xm2aGcWam7j9vFdSNfalbko4rt-RlUOb7bLuL9009bw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: `B2:B` are not proper excel ranges, should your tags be for google sheets instead?

Comment: Yeah this is my mistake i will correct this. No it is for MS Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B>=E1),--(B2:B<=F1),(A2:A=E6)+(E6=""))
```

In MS Excel, try something like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B1000>=E1),--(B2:B1000<=F1),(A2:A1000=E6)+(E6=""))
```

Comment: Thank you very much